# Auto document time of creation of new Java class

Tags: java, netbeans

When I create a new Java file in NetBeans, I get auto documentation for `@author`. How can I setup NetBeans that is also documents the time and date of creation of the class?

I know NetBeans can do it as I get the time and date of creation in new CSS files by default.

Comment: I suggest that you learn to use version control software such as `git`. This tool not only records what time and date a file was created but also tracks time and date of all changes ever made to your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the template files in Netbeans.  Go to `Tools|Templates`.  From the available templates, find the one you want to change, let's say `Java|Java Class`, then select `Open in Editor`

Then goto to [FaqTemplateVariables](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqTemplateVariables) for list of available template variables.  In your case, you're looking for `${date}` and `{$time}`

Then you modify the template the way want, for example...

```
<#assign licenseFirst = "/*">
<#assign licensePrefix = " * ">
<#assign licenseLast = " */">
<#include "${project.licensePath}">

<#if package?? && package != "">
package ${package};

</#if>
/**
 *
 * @author ${user}
 * ${date} ${time}
 */
public class ${name} {

}
```

Then simple create a new "Java Class" - `File|New File|Java|Class` and it should then generate a file similar to this...

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package my.awesome.library;

/**
 *
 * @author noob
 * 25/06/2017 3:19:39 PM
 */
public class Test {

}
```

Now, you'll probably have to go through a number of the other templates and update them, but that gives you a place to start

Comment: It works like a charm! I remember one time I had to change my user account on my favorite Mac simply because I did not know how to change the `@author` in Netbeans. Damn!

Comment: How to apply the date param or any other param to all the types java classes? Because otherwise I need to change every type like separate for interface etc.

Comment: @Yougesh To be honest, I don't think there's away to effect ALL the templates - it's not like a class extension

Answer (score 2):

@MadProgrammer answered well. Just in case as an addition to this answer. U can optionally add properties in the `User.properties` file which is read by the various templates in the `Tools -> Templated ->* configs`. So if u want to add `version` to your Java `classes`. you can define the `@version` in the Java class template and then define the property in the User.properties file as in the following

In Your Java class template

```
....
 /**
  * ${date} ${time}
  * ${version}
  * ...other 
  */
```

U can then set these properties in the `User.properties` file as

```
  version=1.0.0
```

etc